# In Java, how do I get my database table to output in columns with headers and lines?

Tags: java, jdbc

I need the output of my code to have columns of ID, NAME and CALORIES, but I'm not sure 'how'. I would like the id# to automatically populate itself, but when I had attempted what I had found on Oracle, it didn't work.  And how do I go about having lines appear that separate everything?

This is my code:

```
package edu.umsl.java3816.foodItem;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class FoodItemTable {

    Connection fit = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String createTableSQL = "create table FOOD_ITEM(ID INTEGER,NAME VARCHAR(256),CALORIES INTEGER)";
        String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO FOOD_ITEM(ID,NAME,CALORIES) VALUES('1','hamburger','550')";
        String selectSQLStatement = "SELECT * FROM FOOD_ITEM";

        FoodItemTable fit = new FoodItemTable();

        try {
            fit.getConnection();
            fit.createTable(createTableSQL);
            fit.insertSQL(insertTableSQL);
            fit.selectSQL(selectSQLStatement);
            fit.shutdownDB();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getConnection() throws Exception {

        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");

        fit = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem", "sa", // username
                "");

    }

    public void createTable(String sqlStatement) {

        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            statement = fit.createStatement();
            int i = statement.executeUpdate(sqlStatement);

            if (i == -1) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + sqlStatement);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void insertSQL(String insertSQLStatement) {

        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            statement = fit.createStatement();
            int i = statement.executeUpdate(insertSQLStatement);

            if (i == -1) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + insertSQLStatement);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void selectSQL(String selectSQLStatement) {

        Statement statement = null;

        try {
            statement = fit.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectSQLStatement);
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt("ID"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("NAME"));
                System.out.println(rs.getInt("CALORIES"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public void shutdownDB() {

        try {
            fit.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: do you want to show that information in the front end? in the console? or where?

Comment: What is with the spam-tagging? If this is a java question, why tag with MySQL, etc.? (I assume you didn't read the FAQ, so you didn't know you are responsible for managing the tags that appear at the bottom of your post.) I will edit the post for you to remove everything but the java tag.

Comment: I had only added the tags that were "recommended".  And I had thought that stack exchange was here to at least offer some guidance, as far as coding is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

It **looks** like you want to show the results of your query within a console window but in a table style orderly fashion (at least to some extent).

You can do this with the use of a java method but first you will need to place your returned query result set into an two dimensional (2D) Array. Here is how you might accomplish this (utilizing your current ***selectSQL()*** method):

```
public void selectSQL(String selectSQLStatement) {
    PreparedStatement statement;
    int resultSetCount = 0;
    String rowCountSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rCount FROM FOOD_ITEM;";

    try {
        //Get the number of records within that will be
        //retrieved from your query...  
        statement = fit.prepareStatement(rowCountSQL);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) { resultSetCount = rs.getInt("rCount"); } 
        // Are there records to display? 
        if (resultSetCount == 0) {
            // No there isn't
            System.out.println("There are NO Records to display!");
            return; 
        }

        // Yes there is so let's declare our 2D Object Array...
        Object[][] queriedRecords = new Object[resultSetCount][3];

        // And now fill the array...
        statement = fit.prepareStatement(selectSQLStatement);
        rs = statement.executeQuery();
        int counter = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            queriedRecords[counter][0] = rs.getInt("ID");
            queriedRecords[counter][1] = rs.getString("NAME");
            queriedRecords[counter][2] = rs.getInt("CALORIES");
            counter++;
        }

        // Display the retrieved records in Console window...
        // The table header names to be used when printed
        String[] tableHeader = { "ID", "NAME", "CALORIES" };
        consolePrintTable(tableHeader, queriedRecords, 2, false, true); 
    } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

You will notice at the bottom of this method is a call to yet another method named ***consolePrintTable()***. This method will display the retrieved data to the console. Read the JavaDoc I have supplied with this method. Here is the method code :

```
/**
 * This method will take the supplied data and print a table to console in a particular 
 * spaced format.<br><br>
 * 
 * <b>Example Usage:</b><pre>
 * 
 *      final Object[][] table = new Object[4][];
 *      table[0] = new Object[] { "foo", "bar", "baz", "bar2", "foo2", "baz2" };
 *      table[1] = new Object[] { "bar2", "foo2", "baz2", "bar2", "foo2", "baz2" };
 *      table[2] = new Object[] { "baz3", "bar3", "foo3", "bar2", "foo2", "baz2" };
 *      table[3] = new Object[] { "foo4", "bar4", "baz4", "bar2", "foo2", "baz2" };
 *   
 *      String[] h = {"Header 1", "Header 2", "Header 3", "Header 4", "Header 5", "Header 6"};
 *      consolePrintTable(h, table, 4, false, true);
 * 
 *      // Output will be:
 *      
 *      --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *      Header 1    Header 2    Header 3    Header 4    Header 5    Header 6    
 *      --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *      foo         bar         baz         bar2        foo2        baz2        
 *      bar2        foo2        baz2        bar2        foo2        baz2        
 *      baz3        bar3        foo3        bar2        foo2        baz2        
 *      foo4        bar4        baz4        bar2        foo2        baz2</pre>
 * 
 * @param headerData (1D String Array) Column (header) titles for the table. 
 * If no Header is desired then supply <b>null</b><br>
 * 
 * @param tableData (2D Object Array) The table data to display.<br>
 * 
 * @param spacesBetweenCells (Integer) The table that will be printed is always
 * spaced apart from one another based on the widest cell detected within both 
 * supplied header data or the 2D Object Array data. This parameter allows you
 * add additional spacing between each column.<br>
 * 
 * @param options (optional - Boolean) ...<pre>
 * 
 *      rightAlignment      - (Default is false) If boolean true is supplied 
 *                            theTable is displayed as right justified. Boolean
 *                            false make the table display as left justified.
 * 
 *      applyHeaderLines    - (Default is true) By default lines are applied to 
 *                            the table so as to separate the header from table
 *                            data. If false is supplied then header lines are
 *                            not displayed. This option only applies if a Header
 *                            1D String Array is supplied (not null).
 * 
 * </pre><br>
 */
public static void consolePrintTable(String[] headerData, Object[][] tableData, int spacesBetweenCells, boolean... options) {
    if (tableData.length == 0) { return; }
    boolean alignRight = false; // Default is Left Alignment
    boolean addHeaderLines = true;
    if(options.length > 0) { 
        if (options.length >= 1) { alignRight = options[0]; }
        if (options.length == 2) { addHeaderLines = options[1]; }
    }

    // Get the widest Cell needed so that all the
    // table cells will be the same when printed.
    int widestCell = 0;
    for (Object[] tableData1 : tableData) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tableData[0].length; j++) {
            int l = tableData1[j].toString().length();
            if (l > widestCell) { widestCell = l; }
        }
    }
    //Now check for the widest in header (if any)
    if (headerData != null && headerData.length > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < headerData.length; i++) {
            if (headerData[i].length() > widestCell) {
                widestCell = headerData[i].length(); 
            }
        }
    }

    widestCell = (widestCell + spacesBetweenCells);
    // -------------------------------------------

    int columns = tableData[0].length;
    String format = "", alignStrg = "-";
    if (alignRight) { alignStrg = ""; }
    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) { 
        format+= "%" + alignStrg + String.valueOf(widestCell) + "s"; 
    }
    format+= "\n";

    //Print The Header (if any)...
    if (headerData != null && headerData.length > 0) {
        int charCount = columns*widestCell;
        if (!alignRight) { charCount = ((columns*widestCell) - spacesBetweenCells);}
        String gridline = "\n" + String.join("", Collections.nCopies(charCount, "-"));
        if (addHeaderLines) { System.out.println(gridline); }
        for(int i = 0; i < headerData.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%" + alignStrg + String.valueOf(widestCell) + "s", headerData[i]);
        }
        if (addHeaderLines) { System.out.println(gridline); }
        else { System.out.println(""); }
    }

    // Display the Table data...
    for (final Object[] row : tableData) {
        System.out.format(format, row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the data of ID, calories, and name on the front-end (HTML), you can use tables. A simple example would be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>Calories</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>You set the data here</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>..</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```